# extract text from nested div into csv file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I managed to isolate this part of a html file

```
<div class="item_display_label"><strong>**Name of Office:** </strong></div>
<div class="item_display_field">**Dacotah**</div>
<div class="item_display_label"><strong>**Federal Electoral District:** </strong></div>
<div class="item_display_field">
**St. Boniface
(Manitoba)**
</div>
<div class="item_display_label"><strong>**Dates:** </strong></div>
<div class="item_display_field">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="data_table">
<tr>
<th class="th_heading" valign="top">Establishment Re-openings</th>
<th class="th_heading" valign="top">Closings</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="index" valign="top">**1903-05-01**</td>
<td class="index" valign="top">**1970-05-01**</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="item_display_label"><strong>Postmaster Information: </strong></div>
<div class="item_display_label"><strong>**Additional Information:** </strong></div>
<div class="item_display_field">
**Closed due to Rural Mail Delivery service via Headingley, R.R. 1**<br/><br/>
**Sec. 25, Twp. 10, R. 2, WPM - 1903-05-01**<br/><br/>
**Sec. 34, Twp. 10, R. 2, WP**M<br/><br/>
**SW 1/4 Sec. 35, Twp. 10, R. 2, WPM**<br/><br/>
</div>
```

by using:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open("post2.html"))
    with open("post2.txt", "wb") as file:
    for link in soup.find_all('div',['item_display_label','item_display_field']):
    print  link
```

I need to export the **bold** fields into a csv with Beautiful Soup. I tried different ways with no results. The columns of the csv file should be: "Name of Office", "Federal Electoral District", "Opening", "Closing","Info". Any clues?
Many thanks

Edited:

I'm trying to write the csv with this:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import csv
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open("post2.html"))
    f= csv.writer(open("post2.csv", "w"))   
    f.writerow(["Name", "District", "Open", "Close","Info"]) 
    for link in soup.find_all('div', ['item_display_label',   'item_display_field'].__contains__):
   print  link.text.strip()
   Name = link.contents[0]
   District = link.contents[1]
   Open = link.contents[2]
   Close = link.contents[3]
   Info = link.contents[4]
   f.writerow([Name, District, Open, Close, Info])
```

but I obtain only the last field (info) in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("post2.html"))
#for link in soup.find_all('div', lambda cls: cls in ['item_display_label', 'item_display_field']):
for link in soup.find_all('div', ['item_display_label', 'item_display_field'].__contains__):
    print  link.text.strip()
```

Using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) with xpath:

```py
import lxml.html

tree = lxml.html.parse('post2.html')
for x in tree.xpath('.//div[@class="item_display_label"]//text()|.//div[@class="item_display_field"]//text()'):
    print x.strip()
```

Comment: Excellent!! A few comments. There is a table in the middle of the div with dates that are necessary.

Comment: @Gus, Dates are also printed.

Comment: Great!! Now it parsed the dates. I'm trying now to write the csv!! Last thing of the night. Fast way to write the csv? I'm trying f= csv.writer(open("post2.csv", "w"))   # Open the output file for writing before the loop
f.writerow(["Name", "District", "Open", "Close","Info"])

Comment: @Gus, What is the exepected output for csv? (It would be good if you specify that in your question.)

Comment: Sorry, I put bold, but the html code didn't show up. The csv output is "Name", "District", "Open", "Close","Info" .Thank you very much for your interest!!

Comment: @Gus, Please update your question to contain desired csv output. With only column name, I can't figure out what you want.